# How to delete some images while generating a new version of dataset in Roboflow

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, roboflow

I have some 1700 odd source images in my Roboflow project . But i need to delete a lot of images while generating a new version of the dataset .

I don't see any delete source images option anywhere in the Roboflow "Generate new version" page

I'm trying to annotate some images for training a object detection model using YOLOv8 .

Thanks .

Comment: Could you share more about what you're trying to delete? If it's images of a certain type, you may be able to use the "Remap Classes" and "Filter Null" options to achieve it